# How cancelling API request works internally in ASP .NET Core API?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

Suppose I have simple endpoint:

```cs
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
    // something...      
 }
```

And I send some http request via Angular: `let sub = this.http.get<string>("some url").subscribe()` and then before getting response from backend I unsubscribe: `sub.unsubscribe()`

My question is:

**How come cancellationToken on backend have IsCancellationRequested set on true, even though when I monitor outgoing http request there are no more http requests passed to backend?**

Comment: For your question here, it seems what you need figure out is how to monitor outgoing request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are assuming `IsCancellationRequested` is changed from the request initiator.

I do not think this is the case. Instead, I believe the value is actually changed internally by the API whenever the request is aborted or otherwise terminated, to signal to you that you should not waste anymore resources on a closed request. At least, that's my conclusion based on the only [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003978#cancellationtoken-1) I was able to find from Microsoft:

> CancellationToken
>
> Actions can optionally bind a CancellationToken as a parameter. This
> binds RequestAborted that signals when the connection underlying the
> HTTP request is aborted. Actions can use this parameter to cancel long
> running async operations that are executed as part of the controller
> actions.

Answer (score 2):

> How come cancellationToken on backend have IsCancellationRequested set
> on true, even though when I monitor outgoing http request there are no
> more http requests passed to backend?

Cancelling a HTTP (1.1 and 2.0) request means closing the underlying TCP connection. It does not require any more HTTP request to notify the server.

[image]

This is how the server updates the connection status. In case of one party abandoning the connection without proper termination (which is common in DoS attacks and firewalls), then the connection will time out after some time.